# Encoding problems C++

Tags: c++, text, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have this program that is supposed to load everything from a .txt file into a string and then display it. The problem I'm getting is that when I import the contents of the file they look different than if you view it in a simple text editor. This is what it looks like *in a text editor*:

> bvwÅ.wÅ.Å}.ÅsqÄsÇ.sÑs|.]po{o.r}sÅ|Ç.y|}Ö.op}ÉÇ.wÇ

And this is what it looks like when it's imported and printed *in my program*:

> bvw\201.w\201.\201}.\201sq\200s\202.s\204s|.]po{o.r}s\201|\202.y|}\205.op}\203\202.w\202

It seems like some characters are being encoded in a strange way, e.g. swedish "å" is stored as "/201". **I want all of the text that my program handles to be Unicode**, so that I can convert characters back and forth between chars and ints.

This is how I import the text file:

```
//Imports the entire file as a string
                string toBeDecrypted;

                while(getline(inputFile, toBeDecrypted)){
                    string appendtemp;
                    getline(inputFile, appendtemp);
                    toBeDecrypted.append("\n");
                    toBeDecrypted.append(appendtemp);
                }
                inputFile.close();
```

**My program also writes to files**, so I want it to write in Unicode too.

## EDIT

I solved the problem by changing the way that the input file is created, it no longer consists of any ASCII-extended characters.

Comment: What you are seeing are the extended ASCII codes (ranging from 128 to 255).
If you want true unicode support you might want to use std::wstring along with std::wcout and such.
Actually, if you would print the exact string that is returned by getline to another file it should not be any different from your input file.

Comment: What is the encoding used by the editor, and how are you doing the output in your program?

Comment: @Marius Aren't those windows-specific? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: @JamesKanze My editor (Xcode 5.1) tells me the default encoding is UTF-8. The output is simply being displayed in a terminal-like window inside of Xcode.

Comment: Nope, have a look here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: FWIW: I can't find any encoding where the Swedish Å would be
`\201`.  (It would be `'\305'` in ISO 8859-1, or `"\303\205"` in
UTF-8.)

Comment: @Marius Except that that page is not really correct: although it may describe the encoding his editor is using, what it calls "extended ASCII" has nothing to do with ASCII, but is rather some vendor specific encoding, and not very wide spread.

Comment: Ah ok I just learned that the extended ASCII codes are not standardized.

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor But how do you generate this output? And what is actually in the file?  I think Mac is a variant of Unix.  If so, it should have a program called `od`: invoke `od -t 1x` on your file, and see what it displays, to be sure of its contents.  Then read your lines, and output a hex dump of them in the C++, to see how your input is mapped.

Comment: @Marius Extended ASCII is a misnomer.  But there are a number of encodings derived from ASCII which are standard: in western Europe, ISO 8859-1 used to be the defacto standard; today, you'll sometimes see ISO 8859-15.  And UTF-8 is gradually replacing all of the others.

Comment: @JamesKanze The output is just couted. Read the post and you will see what is actually in the file. I have no idea of what a hex dump is or how to use that command, I'm a beginner at C++. I JUST WANT TO BE ABLE TO VIEW CHARACTERS AS THEY ARE SUPPOSED TO BE VIEWED, god dammit how hard can it be 0.o You'd think the people developing operating system and programming languages would have made this easy, but nooo.... Wtf.

Comment: Have you tried std::wcout?

Comment: @Marius I can't find any good information on how to use it, got a link?

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor: you don't have to shout, and yes (as a Brazilian having to deal with Portuguese encoding problems), this is a very, very hard problem because people have input files with various different encodings. So, first of all, you'll have to find out what is the encoding of the original file and then translate it to your current encoding. Even OSX TextEditor is not being capable of doing that, apparently, because the sequences `\201.` `\201}` look suspiciously like utf-8 characters to me: and to make things worse, sometimes, buggy tools double-utf8-encode things.

Comment: Google for Unicode and UTF8 (Wikipedia is a good start)

Comment: `std::wcout << "\x80\x81\x82\x83" << std::endl;` produces `Çüéâ` on windows with msvc. This might or might not work for you, I never bothered with that kind of console output.

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor Regretfully, handling characters is complicated, for historical reasons.  There are many different encodings, and without understanding something about the implications, it's generally impossible to get anywhere.